# Why does my app include "find account on device" permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I can figure out why my app has "find account on device" permission. I havent added it to the manifest file, which looks like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

I can read in a [similair post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490598/why-does-my-app-has-the-read-phone-state-permission-although-its-not-declared-i), that it might be something about an included library, but I dont see any problems there. I am using the following libraries:

- [dibs-library-1.3.0.jar](http://tech.dibspayment.com/D2/Integrate/Mobile/Android)
- [zbar.jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/AndroidSDK/) (v. 0.2)
- armeabi.jar (needed for zbar)
- armeabi-v7a.jar (needed for zbar)
- x86.jar (needed for zbar)

Comment: `dibs-library-1.3.0.jar` is included for some inapp payment and payment needs identification of who you are. Seems that "find account on device" legit.