# Does using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT automatically add the READ_PHONE_STATE permission?

Tags: android, permissions

In my app, I'm checking the [Build.VERSION.SDK_INT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) in order to conditionally warn users that they need to update Android in order to use a particular feature. It looks something like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15) {
    // Good to go
} else {
    // Needs an Android update
}
```

In the latest update I released, the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission has been added, even though it is **not** declared in `AndroidManifest.xml` which looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    ...
```

I've found a couple of related questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277242), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490598)), and I'll try to test later if my dependencies are causing the issue.

But just out of curiosity (and since I can't access my code right now), will using `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` cause the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission to be added automatically?

Or better yet, *what might cause this permission to automatically be added*?

Comment: Adding a piece of java code to your app will never cause permissions to be added. The answer to the first StackOverflow question you referenced seems to cover the possible causes well.

Comment: @NasaGeek that's kinda what I thought... I suppose that I'll have to wait until I get home to figure out my dependencies and their permissions.

Comment: People can't just update their Android Version. Instead of telling the user to update, just make that feature unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT cause the READ_PHONE_STATE permission to be added automatically?

No.

> Or better yet, what might cause this permission to automatically be added?

[A library, most likely](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll start debugging the dependencies when I get home!