# Permission READ_PHONE_STATE automatically added when using play services 12.0.0

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-permissions, google-play-console

I changed my gradle build file to use the latest Google play services version (11.8.0 -> 12.0.0) and uploaded the APK to the Google Play Console. When I tried to release, I got a warning that READ_PHONE_STATE permission had been added. If I roll back to 11.8.0, this warning disappears.

I use the following services:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:12.0.0'
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0'
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.0'
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.0'
```

It seems it was automatically added to a generated manifest.xml even though I don't need this permission (at least I didn't for play services 11.8.0). Having looked around, it seems it is an issue when a minSdk/targetSdk is not declared in an included library.

Does anyone know what is happening and how I can get rid of this permission please?

Thanks,
Riz

Edit: this was marked by a moderator as an exact duplicate of [Why has the READ_PHONE_STATE permission been added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668549/why-has-the-read-phone-state-permission-been-added) . Unfortunately the solution in that question was that Play services was updated in 10.0.1 to fix this issue. It seems that version 12.0.0 reintroduces this issue so am looking for a solution.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and this question shouldn't be marked as duplicate, can the one who duplicated this question tell me how this an exact duplicate of an existing question!

Comment: A solution (as well mentioned in the duplicate) that works for any google play version is to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml. I am guessing google will fix this again in 12.0.1.

Comment: I guess so, was just hoping for something less hacky. Cheers, will stick that in.

Comment: Yes, I'm just update yesterday. And get that issue too. But is not problem I think. This one release notes for it [https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases] (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

*-license POM dependencies have no minSdkVersion / targetSdkVersion set, which means that the implied targetSdkVersion is 1. This adds READ_PHONE_STATE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions for apps using 12.0.0.*